# Macro directive sequence in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm reading [C Programming: A Modern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393979504). In Ch14 exercise #11:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 100

void f(void);

int main(void) {
    f();
#ifdef N
#undef N
#endif
    return 0;
}

void f(void) {
#if defined(N)
    printf("N is %d\n", N);
#else
    printf("N is undefined\n");
#endif
}
```

The output is `N is undefined`, while I expected it to be `N is 100`. However, if we move the content of function `f` into `main`, it works as expected:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 100

void f(void);

int main(void) {
#if defined(N)
    printf("N is %d\n", N);
#else
    printf("N is undefined\n");
#endif

#ifdef N
#undef N
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `N is 100`. Why so? Why the preprocessor can retroactively apply the `#undef` into `f()`? Thanks.

Comment: Think of the preprocessor as a sophisticated edit program that edits the source code, top to bottom, before the compiler sees the code...

Comment: The directives are not *in* either `main` or `f`. They are on line 3, 10, 11,  and so forth. As far as the preprocessor is concerned, there doesn't even have to be a valid C program amidst its directives.

Comment: Tangential note: `#undef N` is specified to do nothing when N isn't defined, so wrapping it with `#ifdef N` was unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro preprocessing takes place before other steps of compilation, let alone runtime evaluation. It's line-by-line, you can think of it as a text replacement. So, when you write `#undef N` in `main()`, then you already undefine the macro; it'll not be defined in `f()`.

Of course, if you check it before undefining it (but after defining it as `100`), then it'll have the value you'd expect.